# SPA style entry rendering, SEO implications

Tags: templating, seo

I'm working on implementing a layout that involves a listing page, that when an entry is clicked, the content slides in from the side and fills the screen.

Doing this in the style of an SPA via ajax or Vue.js is fairly straightforward, but I'm unclear on how to implement in Craft while maintaining SEO "crawlability" via something like server-side pre-rendering or such.

I'm not even sure where to start, any direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create actual pages for the content that is being loaded. Not only will this help with SEO, it will act as a fallback for anyone who is not using javascript. You can link to these pages from your current links so that search engines can crawl through them, but for those with javascript you can load the content asynchronously.